# Representing matrix exponential in terms of matrix powers via Cayley-Hamilton

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential, cayley-hamilton

> Using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, show that for a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, $$e^A = c_1 A + c_0 I$$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants.

---

This problem came to me absolutely from nowhere and I have no clue how to solve it. Basically the theorem tells that every square matrix satisfies its own characteristic equation. By this theorem, we can find the exponent of a square matrix and its inverse. But does it really give a clue how to find anything like $e^A$? Help me to solve this

Comment: Hint: the characteristic polynomial is quadratic. How can we simplify higher powers of the matrix exponential with this?

Comment: @user600016 If $ P_1\lambda^2+P_2\lambda+P_3=0$ be the ch. eqn, then I can replace $\lambda$ by $A$. But after that how do I bring $e$ into my calculation?

Comment: By definition, $e^A=I+A+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\frac{A^3}{3!}+\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the question:

**Lemma 1** For any polynomial $P,$ $P(A) = c_1(P) A + c_2(P)I.$
**Proof sketch** The right hand side is equal to the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $\chi(x),$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A.$

**Lemma 2** If $P_n$ is the $n$-th Taylor polynomial of $\exp,$ the coefficients  $c_{1, 2}(P_n)$ converge as $n$ goes to infinity.

You can go from here.

Comment: $e^A$ has coefficients $1, \dfrac 1 {2!}, \dfrac 1 {3!}$ etc and that of $\chi(x)$ will be $P_1, P_2, P_3$ where these are all constants. So on division, how the coefficients of the remainder will be functions of $P$?   Also what will be $P(A)$ in this case?